# how to convert? [semanticui.less to semanticui.css]

Tags: semantic-ui

I am using semantic ui less version and tried to compile it using gulp but not able to do this.

Can somebody give me an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set up a build task to watch the files you are working on and process your less into css. Take a look at Grunt  http://gruntjs.com/getting-started (or alternately at Gulp, which is another great task runner)

Here's an article about automating your workflow with grunt: http://kappataumu.com/articles/grunt-automate-your-webdev-workflow.html

this is the actual module that Grunt will use to process your less: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-less
but it will do so automatically once you have it set up

Comment: can grunt compiles less file importing another less file ? as its in semantic.less

Comment: it sure can, just use the `@import "library";` syntax towards the top of your top level less file, before listing all your other less files

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [Getting Started](http://learnsemantic.com/guide/expert.html) guide for Semantic UI to learn how to use its build system.

In short, you need to do the following steps:

1. [Install Node.js for your platform](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation), if you don't already have it.
2. Install gulp using *npm*, the Node.js package manager:

   `npm install -g gulp`
3. Download Semantic UI and navigate to its directory:

   `cd semantic-ui`
4. Install all the project dependencies:

   `npm install`
5. Run the installer. The installer will run automatically when you first run gulp in the Semantic UI directory with no arguments:

   `gulp`
6. Follow the installer steps to configure Semantic UI as per your needs.
7. After this, you should be able to use the following gulp tasks:

   - `gulp build` to rebuild Semantic UI from its sources (this includes its LESS files)
   - `gulp watch` to watch for changes in source files and automatically build when needed (or you can just use `gulp`)
   - `gulp install` to re-run the installer

Comment: I have to use semantic ui less  so what  I write in my package.json file

Comment: If you're referring to package.json from Semantic UI, you shouldn't edit it. If you're referring to your own package.json, you shouldn't edit that either, since Semantic UI includes all the needed tools to build it. Just follow the instructions from the Getting Started guide.